# Как дать права определенному пользователю на чтение файла?

Tags: linux, файлы, права

Есть два пользователя: user1 и user2. И есть два файла: file1 и file2. Как задать права, чтобы каждый из этих пользователей мог читать файлы друг друга, сам мог и читать и запускать и редактировать СВОЙ файл, а остальные пользователи ничего не могли?

P.S. Владельцы файла соответственно user1 и user2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> сам мог и читать и запускать и редактировать СВОЙ файл:

```
$ chmod u+rwx свой.файл
```

> остальные пользователи ничего не могли

```
$ chmod o= свой.файл
```

предыдущие два пункта можно совместить в одну команду:

```
$ chmod u+rwx,o= свой.файл
```

> чтобы каждый из этих пользователей мог читать

1. если файловая система **не** поддерживает [*acl*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL), то сначала потребуются полномочия суперпользователя — надо будет создать группу, в которую будут входить (только) эти два пользователя:

   ```
   $ sudo groupadd общая.группа
   $ sudo usermod -aG общая.группа пользователь1
   $ sudo usermod -aG общая.группа пользователь2
   ```

   и пользователь сможет изменять принадлежность файла группе:

   ```
   $ chown :общая.группа свой.файл
   ```

   затем, чтобы другие члены этой группы могли файл только читать:

   ```
   $ chmod g=r свой.файл
   ```
2. если файловая система **поддерживает** *acl*, можно воспользоваться программами *setfacl/getfacl*:

   1. посмотреть текущие правила *acl*:

      ```
      $ getfacl свой.файл
      # file: свой.файл
      # owner: пользователь1
      # group: группа1
      user::rwx
      group::r--
      other::---
      ```
   2. дать второму пользователю право чтения:

      ```
      $ setfacl -m u:пользователь2:r свой.файл
      ```
   3. проверить, что получилось:

      ```
      $ getfacl свой.файл
      # file: свой.файл
      # owner: пользователь1
      # group: группа1
      user::rwx
      user:пользователь2:r--
      group::r--
      mask::r--
      other::---
      ```

---

- дополнительная информация про [posix acl](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/access_control_list)

Comment: чем ваш ответ от моего отличается?

Comment: @perfect, 1. примерами команд. 2. наличием второго варианта (setfacl).

Comment: я бы фенечки типо acl не использовал ибо linux на большинстве устройствах минималистичен. и читать и записывать собственный файл и так можно. а для поробностей есть команда man

Comment: @perfect, для случаев, когда файловая не поддерживает acl (или поддержка намеренно отключена), я тоже привёл примеры. // p.s. а минус вашему ответу дали, я подозреваю, именно за краткость.

Comment: да согласен мой ответ победней вашего кажется на первый взгляд ) .

Comment: я бы добавил ссылки:
http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/access_control_list

Answer (score 2):

Читайте встроенную справочную систему:

[man  chmod](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&topic=chmod)

Этой командой можно выставить право читать ваши файлы для группы пользователей, соответственно читаем встроенную справку:

[man chgrp](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=chgrp&category=1&russian=0)

и создаем группу с именем что то типа `read_file1_and_file2` ([man addgroup](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=addgroup&category=8&russian=0)), заводим туда этих двух пользователей и выставляем в правах доступа к вашим файлам как: `чтение для группы read_file1_and_file2`

Comment: немного не понял там про u. Там же нельзя выбрать пользователя. Только группу, которая владеет файлом.

Comment: @kot_maplu3 дополнил